# How can I create multiple category pages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-list, category-listing

Actually, I want to create different files for every category page (every product listing page).

For that I have:

1. Created customlist.phtml from list.phtml or copied the code of list.phtml and create
2. Assign customlist.phtml in admin side (admin → category → Layout
   section)

But it is not working:

> **Error:-**`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function count() on null`

Layout Section Code:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="category.products">
        <block name="product_list" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/customlist.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

How can I create multiple category pages in Magento 2?

Comment: can you please paste your admin->category->Layout section code

Comment: @SunilPatel i have updated code now

Comment: @SunilPatel when i add custom text like echo "hello"; then it is working but after copy all code of list.phtml it shows error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jaimin for toolbar you need to do something like this.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="category.products">
      <block name="product_list" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
          <action method="setTemplate">
              <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list2.phtml</argument>
          </action>
          <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                   </block>
                   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                       <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                   </block>
                   <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                       <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                   </action>
      </block>
  </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 4):

you mention wrong block name please check below code

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="category.products">
        <block name="product_list" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/customlist.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could reveal the wrong block name?

Comment: @Sunil Patel I have found one issue after adding your given code. I could not see pagination in my custom listing page. except that all are working as expected. can you help me in that please

Comment: Maybe you need to change Block.